# Restrict Outlook All-day Event that span multiple days

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, filtering, appointment

Further to my last question, I’d like to search for free appointment spaces in my outlook calendar and save the closest 2 x 1 hour slots that land on different days. The code is pretty much working. However the only situation that I can't get to work is where there are all-day appointments that span multiple days. I don't think the standard restrict filter will notice these appointments.

I've built (not shown below) a workaround that temporarily splits up the multi-day appointment into individual appointments and then re-instates the original meeting setup after the code finishes. However, this code is slow to execute and so I'd like to revisit the filter on how to include all-day appointments that span multiple days.

The filter I've got so far is:
(where i = 0 = the first/current day). 'i' will iterate until 13 (so that the code searches over a 2 week period).

Edit: where dtmAppt = current date. With each i though 1 day is added to dtmAppt.

Edit2: I'm having a good think and wonder whether this isn't where my code is failing as I think I should be grabbing any and all "alldayevents" seeing as my filter has:

```
OR ([AllDayEvent] = True AND [BusyStatus] <> 0))"
```

So instead I think it might be here:

```
Select Case DateValue(dtmAppt)
            Case DateValue(Format(olAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

For each iteration of 'i' the dtmAppt will also move on by 1 day. The olAppt.start though does not change on an all-day event that spans multiple days - I believe the start date/time is when it first starts (i.e. on the 1st day); so it is being successfully ignored as a potential date to be booked on for day 1, but day 2 it doesn't ignore it and won't recognise that it shouldn't be able to book on this day.
Perhaps I need another loop to check the start and end times of all possible appointments (i.e. not just on the day) before allowing it to execute this code. What do people think?

Original place that I thought I wasn't capturing the alldayevents spanning multiple days:

```
If i = 0 Then
    ' Get the current time of day
    Dim currentTime As Date
    currentTime = Now()

     ' Use the current time of day as the start time for the search

    strDay = "(([Start] >= '" & Format(currentTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn") & "' AND [Start] < '" & Format(DateAdd("d", 1, dtmAppt), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "') OR ([AllDayEvent] = True AND [BusyStatus] <> 0))"

Else

    strDay = "(([Start] >= '" & dtmAppt & "' AND [Start] < '" & DateAdd("d", 1, dtmAppt) & "') OR [AllDayEvent] = True AND  [BusyStatus] <> 0)"

End If
```

Can anyone help me work out how to find these specific appointments?

The remainder of the code block in case it helps is as follows:

```
Sub ScheduleAppointments()
    Dim dtmFirstAppt As Date
    Dim dtmLastAppt As Date
    Dim intDefaultAppt As Integer

    ' Set the default values for appointment times and duration
    dtmFirstAppt = #8:00:00 AM#
    dtmLastAppt = #9:00:00 PM#
    intDefaultAppt = 60 ' in minutes
    
   
    ' Find all-day events with free status and prompt user to continue
    FindFreeAllDayEvents

    ' Call the function to find and schedule appointments
    ScheduleFreeTimeAppointments dtmFirstAppt, dtmLastAppt, intDefaultAppt
End Sub

Function FindFreeTime(dtmAppt As Date, dtmFirstAppt As Date, dtmLastAppt As Date, intDefaultAppt As Integer, i As Integer) As String

    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Namespace
    Dim OLFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olAppt As Object
    Dim OLAppts As Outlook.Items
    Dim strDay As String
    Dim strList As String
    Dim dtmNext As Date
    Dim intDuration As Integer
    Dim dtmEnd As Date

    Const C_Procedure = "FindFreeTime"

    dtmNext = dtmFirstAppt

    If i = 0 And dtmFirstAppt < Now Then
        dtmNext = TimeValue(Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Time) + 1, 0, 0))
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set objOL = g_objOL
    
If i = 0 Then
    ' Get the current time of day
    Dim currentTime As Date
    currentTime = Now()

     ' Use the current time of day as the start time for the search

    strDay = "(([Start] >= '" & Format(currentTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn") & "' AND [Start] < '" & Format(DateAdd("d", 1, dtmAppt), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "') OR ([AllDayEvent] = True AND [BusyStatus] <> 0))"

Else

    strDay = "(([Start] >= '" & dtmAppt & "' AND [Start] < '" & DateAdd("d", 1, dtmAppt) & "') OR [AllDayEvent] = True AND  [BusyStatus] <> 0)"

End If


    Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Get the local calendar folder
    Set OLFldr = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    ' Get the appointments for the selected day
    Set OLAppts = OLFldr.Items.Restrict(strDay)
     ' Sort the collection (required by IncludeRecurrences)
    OLAppts.Sort "[Start]", False
    

     ' Make sure recurring appointments are included
    OLAppts.IncludeRecurrences = True

    With OLAppts
         ' capture start time and duration of each item
        Set olAppt = .GetFirst
        Do While TypeName(olAppt) <> "Nothing"
             ' find first free timeslot
            Select Case DateValue(dtmAppt)
'            If (olAppt.Start <= dtmAppt And olAppt.End > dtmAppt) Or _
'   (olAppt.Start >= dtmAppt And olAppt.Start < DateAdd("d", 1, dtmAppt)) Then
   
            Case DateValue(Format(olAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
            Debug.Print Format(olAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy Hh:Nn")

                    If Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn") < Format(olAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn") Then

                         ' find gap before next appointment starts
                        If Format(olAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn") < Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn") Then
                            intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(olAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn"))
                        Else
                            intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn"))
                        End If

                         ' can we fit an appointment into the gap?
                        If intDuration >= intDefaultAppt Then
                    strList = strList & Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn ampm") & ";" & Format(DateAdd("n", intDuration, dtmNext), "Hh:Nn ampm") & ";"
                    End If
            End If
             ' find first available time after appointment
            dtmNext = DateAdd("n", olAppt.Duration + intDuration, _
            dtmNext)

             ' don't go beyond last possible appointment time
            If dtmNext > dtmLastAppt Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End Select

        intDuration = 0

        Set olAppt = .GetNext
        If dtmNext > dtmLastAppt Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    
    Loop
End With

 ' capture remainder of day
intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn"))

If intDuration >= intDefaultAppt Then
    strList = strList & Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn ampm") & _
    ";" & Format(DateAdd("n", intDuration, dtmNext), "Hh:Nn ampm") & _
    ";"
End If
0
FindFreeTime = strList

ExitHere:
Set olAppt = Nothing
Set OLAppts = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
Exit Function

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & C_Procedure & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Resume ExitHere
End Function

Sub ScheduleFreeTimeAppointments(ByVal dtmFirstAppt As Date, ByVal dtmLastAppt As Date, ByVal intDefaultAppt As Integer)
    Dim strList     As String
    Dim dtmAppt     As Date
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim found       As Integer
    Dim intCount    As Integer
    Dim dtmLastScheduled As Date

    ' Create a temporary appointment starting from the next whole hour
    Dim dtmStart As Date
    Dim dtmEnd As Date
    dtmStart = Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Minute(Now), 60), 0)
    dtmEnd = DateAdd("n", 60, dtmStart)
    Dim olApt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set olApt = g_objOL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    olApt.Start = dtmStart
    olApt.End = dtmEnd
    olApt.Subject = "Temporary Appointment"
    olApt.Save

    ' Check if the first day should be skipped
    dtmAppt = Date
    If TimeValue(Now) > dtmLastAppt Then
        dtmAppt = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
    End If
    
    For i = 0 To 13
        
        If i = 0 Then        ' First day

        If DateValue(Now) = dtmAppt And TimeValue(Now) > dtmLastAppt Then
            ' Current time is after dtmFirstAppt, so set dtmFirstAppt to the next whole hour
            dtmFirstAppt = TimeValue(Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Time) + 1, 0, 0))

            Dim durDefaultAppt As Double
            Dim timeDefaultAppt As Date

            timeDefaultAppt = TimeValue(dtmFirstAppt)        ' Convert it into the time of day only.

            'Calculate the end of the appoint
            Dim timeEndAppt As Date
            timeEndAppt = DateAdd("n", intDefaultAppt, timeDefaultAppt)

            'Check if the end of the appointment is equal to or greater than the time of logging off.
            If timeEndAppt >= dtmLastAppt Then
                'if so then move on to the next day.
                i = 1
                'otherwise carry on
            End If
        End If
    Else        ' All other days
        dtmFirstAppt = #8:00:00 AM#
    End If
    If i > 0 Then

    dtmAppt = DateAdd("d", 1, dtmAppt)

    End If

    If Weekday(dtmAppt) >= 2 And Weekday(dtmAppt) <= 6 Then        ' Check if the date is a weekday
    
    strList = FindFreeTime(dtmAppt, dtmFirstAppt, dtmLastAppt, intDefaultAppt, i)
    If Len(strList) > 0 Then        ' A free timeslot was found
    Dim arrSlots()  As String
    Dim j           As Integer

    ' Schedule appointments for the free slots
    arrSlots = Split(strList, ";")
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrSlots) - 1 Step 2
        dtmStart = CDate(dtmAppt & " " & arrSlots(j))
        dtmEnd = CDate(dtmAppt & " " & arrSlots(j + 1))

        ' Check if the appointment is within the next two weeks

        If dtmStart >= Now() And DateDiff("n", Now(), dtmStart) >= 60 And dtmStart <= DateAdd("d", 14, Now()) Then

            If DateValue(dtmStart) >= DateAdd("d", 1, DateValue(dtmLastScheduled)) Then
      ' Schedule appointment only if it's on a different day than the last scheduled appointment
                If ScheduleOutlookAppointment(dtmStart, DateAdd("n", intDefaultAppt, dtmStart)) Then        ' Set the appointment duration to intDefaultAppt
                    intCount = intCount + 1

                    arrAppointments(intCount, 1) = dtmStart ' Store the date of the appointment
                    Debug.Print Format(dtmStart, "dd/mm/yyyy Hh:Nn")
                    Debug.Print arrAppointments(1, 1)
                    Debug.Print arrAppointments(2, 1)

                    arrAppointments(intCount, 2) = intDefaultAppt ' Store the duration of the appointment
                    dtmLastScheduled = dtmStart        ' Update the date of the last scheduled appointment

                    ' Stop scheduling appointments once we've scheduled two
                    If intCount = 2 Then

                        Exit For
                    End If
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Error scheduling appointment For " & dtmStart
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j

found = found + 1
Else
   ' Debug.Print "No free timeslots found For " & Format(dtmAppt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If
Else
   ' Debug.Print "Skipping weekend day " & Format(dtmAppt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If

' Exit the loop if we've scheduled two appointments
If intCount = 2 Then
    Exit For
End If
Next i

If intCount = 0 Then
    SendInitialEmail "John", "Sarah", DateSerial(2023, 3, 6), #1/1/4501#, "", #1/1/4501#, ""
ElseIf intCount = 1 Then
    SendInitialEmail "John", "Sarah", DateSerial(2023, 3, 6), arrAppointments(1, 1), Format(arrAppointments(1, 1), "h:mm AM/PM"), #1/1/4501#, ""
ElseIf intCount = 2 Then
    SendInitialEmail "John", "Sarah", DateSerial(2023, 3, 6), arrAppointments(1, 1), Format(arrAppointments(1, 1), "h:mm AM/PM"), arrAppointments(2, 1), Format(arrAppointments(2, 1), "h:mm AM/PM")
End If

If intCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "No available time slots found within the next two weeks.", vbInformation
Else

End If

    olApt.Delete
    Set olApt = Nothing
'    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub

Sub FindFreeAllDayEvents()
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim DateStart As Date
    Dim DateEnd As Date
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim DisplayEndDate As Date
    Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim CountFreeAllDayEvents As Integer
    
    Set olFolder = g_objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    
    ' Define the two-week period
    DateStart = Date
    DateEnd = DateAdd("d", 14, DateStart)
    Filter = "[Start] >= '" & Format(DateStart, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "' And [End] <= '" & Format(DateEnd, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "'"
    Set Items = olFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    
    ' Count the number of all-day events with free status
    For Each olAppt In Items
        If olAppt.AllDayEvent And olAppt.BusyStatus = olFree Then
            CountFreeAllDayEvents = CountFreeAllDayEvents + 1
        End If
    Next olAppt
    
    ' Display the message box with the count and prompt the user to continue
    If CountFreeAllDayEvents > 0 Then
        Response = MsgBox("You have " & CountFreeAllDayEvents & " all-day appointments that are marked in your calendar as being free/available to be booked. You may have incorrectly marked them in this way, rather than setting yourself to being busy." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        "In the following message boxes, please state whether you want them updated to busy on your behalf or not. If you leave them as being available, then this script may offer a meeting date on one of these days as it will think you are free." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                          "Press OK to continue.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Free All-Day Events")
    
    End If
    
    For Each olAppt In Items
        If olAppt.AllDayEvent And olAppt.BusyStatus = olFree Then
            ' Adjust the end date if the event is only one day long
            If DateDiff("d", olAppt.Start, olAppt.End) = 1 Then
                DisplayEndDate = olAppt.Start
            Else
                DisplayEndDate = olAppt.End
            End If
            
            ' Print the start date, end date, and subject as a bullet point
            If DateDiff("d", olAppt.Start, olAppt.End) = 1 Then
                Debug.Print Format(olAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy") & ": " & olAppt.Subject
            Else
                Debug.Print Format(olAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & Format(DisplayEndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & ": " & olAppt.Subject
            End If
            
            ' Ask the user whether they want to change the BusyStatus to olBusy or leave it as it is
            Response = MsgBox("Do you want to change the status of the following event to Busy?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                              Format(olAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy") & IIf(DateDiff("d", olAppt.Start, olAppt.End) = 1, "", " - " & Format(DisplayEndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")) & ": " & olAppt.Subject, _
vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Change Event Status")

        ' If the user selects "Yes", change the BusyStatus to olBusy
        If Response = vbYes Then
            olAppt.BusyStatus = olBusy
            olAppt.Save
        End If
    End If
Next olAppt

Set olAppt = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst @Niton has provided a solution, it's quite a bit different from this current approach and opens up other issues such as not grabbing up to date event information. This also maybe rolled out to other users so getting them to change settings in their profile is a turn off! So ideally I'm still looking for an answer to the question above!

Answer (score 0):

[ExchangeUser.GetFreeBusy method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.getfreebusy) identifies free appointment spaces.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetOpenInterval()

    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.getfreebusy

    Dim oCurrentUser As ExchangeUser
    Dim FreeBusy As String
    Dim BusySlot As Long
    Dim DateBusySlot As Date
    Dim i As Long
    
    Const SlotLength = 60
    
    'Get ExchangeUser for CurrentUser
    If Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Type = "EX" Then
    
        Set oCurrentUser = Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
        
        FreeBusy = oCurrentUser.GetFreeBusy(Now, SlotLength)
        Debug.Print FreeBusy
        
        Dim j As Long
        j = 1
        Dim timeSlot1 As Date
        
        For i = 1 To Len(FreeBusy)
        
            If CLng(Mid(FreeBusy, i, 1)) = 0 Then
            
                'get the number of minutes into the day for free interval
                BusySlot = (i - 1) * SlotLength
                'get an actual date/time
                DateBusySlot = DateAdd("n", BusySlot, Date)
                
                'To refine this function, substitute actual
                'workdays and working hours in date/time comparison
                If TimeValue(DateBusySlot) >= TimeValue(#8:00:00 AM#) And _
                  TimeValue(DateBusySlot) <= TimeValue(#5:00:00 PM#) And _
                  Not (Weekday(DateBusySlot) = vbSaturday Or _
                  Weekday(DateBusySlot) = vbSunday) Then
                    
                    If j = 1 Then
                    
                        If DateBusySlot > Now Then
                            timeSlot1 = DateBusySlot
                            Debug.Print oCurrentUser.name & " open interval:" & vbCrLf & _
                              Format(DateBusySlot, "dddd, mmm d yyyy hh:mm AMPM")
                            j = 2
                        End If
                        
                    Else
                    
                        If day(DateBusySlot) <> day(timeSlot1) Then
                            Debug.Print oCurrentUser.name & " open interval:" & vbCrLf & _
                              Format(DateBusySlot, "dddd, mmm d yyyy hh:mm AMPM")
                            Exit For
                        End If
                        
                    End If
                    
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you; however if I run the code, I will get a free appointment say on Monday 27th at 8am. If I book in a meeting in my diary for that time (or get VBA to book it), and then re-run the code; it still thinks I am available at the same time. Does freebusy get updated at certain intervals only?

Comment: Set FreeBusy update frequency in Calendar Options of Calendar settings.

Comment: Can you force an update to happen within vba?

Comment: Unknown. You could post a new question.